# How to make a foreground image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, foreground

I've got this image and i want to put it over my website as a foregound. It should overlap the background and the elements. I'm using CSS.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aawxonln4h1i5dt/Snow.png?dl=0

Comment: `position:absolute; bottom:0;z-index:9999` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want something like this:

Html (place somewhere on top):

```
<img src="URL_TO_IMAGE" id="overlay"/>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay{
width:100%;
position:absolute; /*You may also use fixed depending on your needs.*/
left:0;
top:0; /*If you want it at the bottom you probably want bottom:0 instead*/
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Could you also use CSS classes? Like <img class="one"> and .one {CSS porperties}